# Could someone help me find a Tanakh vowelised according to the Yemenite Tradition?

Tags: minhag, tanach, torah-reading, vowels-nekudot

I would like to study the Yemenite traditions of pronounciation in reading. However, I'm unsure where to find a copy of the Tanakh with such notation. If anyone could assist me in this it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

The text of the Tanakh in the Yemenite tradition is vowelised essentially the same as standard editions. There are some vocalisation differences across Tanakh between versions, but they rarely exclusively localised to Yemenite vs. rest-of-the-world.

But if you want a specifically Yemenite source, [here](https://www.nteiman.co.il/tort_amt/) is an online Ḥumash broken down according to parasha.

Comment: Have you seen this: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Babylonian_Supralinear_Punctuation,_from_Yemenite_Siddur,_April_2015.jpg

Comment: Seeing a version of Nakh would be very helpful too I'm sure since, while differences in Torah are perhaps more significant, they are generally much more subtle.